Google PlayIntegrity API validate token via PHP
I try to get device verdict with google play integrity token, but always have a million errors and I can't understand whats wrong. My Code:
<?php

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\PlayIntegrity;
use Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest;

require  'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');

$client->addScope(PlayIntegrity::PLAYINTEGRITY);
$token = 'token';
$service = new PlayIntegrity($client);
$tokenRequest = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest();
$tokenRequest->setIntegrityToken($token);
$result = $service->v1->decodeIntegrityToken('com.package', $tokenRequest);


If run it I get an error "Integrity token cannot be decoded due to invalid arguments"
Help please, what should I do?
